# Detecting the likelihood of a passage consisting of certain words

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining

This is a homework assignment. I am not necessarily looking for exact solutions but open answers and possible strategies. I have a collection of passages and a collection  of words. I need to detect which of these passages possibly consist of **certain keywords** and output the titles' of these passages

The brute force way would be to do simple string matching and checking if the passage consists of the required strings, but I don't think that would be a great solution at all. Also, the homework asks me to determine if the passage is **likely** to consist of the keywords, which essentially implies some kind of machine learning/data mining would be involved.

All your input is highly valued, Thanks much!

P.S: If it matters, I am going to solve this using Java programming language.

Comment: Normally you won't be assigned something that has nothing to do with what you're covering in class... have you been studying machine learning?

Comment: I'd recommend removing all punctuation and splitting around whitespace to get an array of words, and then sorting and binary searching it to check if the passage consists certain strings.  As for the machine learning part, that will take quite a bit more.

Comment: @Vulcan I believe he's already considered that (likely what he meant by the "_bruteforce way_")

Comment: I understood the "bruteforce way" to be simply using String#contains.

Comment: @user1020069 when multiple people have commented, it is necessary you tag them to ensure they are notified.

Comment: @vulcan I will use a stop list to, well, stop some of the words and the punctuation etc

Comment: @Vulcan putting them into an into a hash table would not be an efficient way to go about doing it. it is still technically scanning the entire list to access each word for multiple passages this is after they have been stop listed

Comment: @user1020069, is it required high accuracy or simple implementation ? If simple then can go with bayes/naive bayes, otherwise http://www.google.it/#hl=it&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=passage+retrieval+based+language+models&oq=passage+retrieval+based+language+models&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.969.969.0.2100.1.1.0.0.0.0.74.74.1.1.0...0.0...1c.VYouiPaYfMA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=bb5c3f3a826b5b69&biw=1366&bih=643

Comment: In the first case you can find lots of open source codes and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your task correctly, but you could use a Bloom filter.

Bloom filter is a probabilistic data structure: it tells us that the element either definitely is not in the set or may be in the set.

Look at explanation of it on [guava library page](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained) or [play with a simple implementation](http://llimllib.github.com/bloomfilter-tutorial/) to see how this works.

Comment: this seems pretty cool.... I guess I can make the passages the a

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Lucene.

Here are some slightly advanced references:

http://www.cnlp.org/apachecon2005/AdvancedLucene.ppt

http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~tphan/publications/trec07.pdf

http://stp.ling.uu.se/~joerg/paper/tema05-final.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The machine learning/data mining approach would require a large amount of data (training data) which you didn't mention having.

The **likely** word might suggest using some form of pattern matching (a more relaxed one, not the exact word) .

Comment: by your approach, the first step is to simply reduce the passage by applying a stoplist and just converting them into lowercases, store em in  a hash table, check for the existence of the keywords....?? not sure if this is a great way to go about doing it. I can always train the data right ?

Comment: @user1020069, add verbs normal form conversion also.

Answer (score 0):

I once had an assignment which consisted of building a search engine for a given 
set of documents. We would parse them and build an inverted index and then use a cosine metric to perform queries using key words. We also had a list of stopwords, and turned all key words to lowercase.

[Here's some basic theory](http://www.slideshare.net/mcjenkins/the-search-engine-index-presentation), with references to more advanced material.